Finding infimum and supremum of a set of cyclic sums
I am trying to find the supremum and infimum of the following set:
$$
\left\{ \frac{a_1}{a_1 + a_2 + a_3} + \frac{a_2}{a_2 + a_3 + a_1} + \cdots + \frac{a_{n-2}}{a_{n-2} + a_{n-1} + a_n} + \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-1} + a_n + a_1} + \frac{a_n}{a_n + a_1 + a_2} : a_1, \dots, a_n > 0, n \geq 3 \right\}
$$
where $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ are positive real numbers and $n$ is an integer with $n \geq 3$.
I have determined that the infimum and supremum of the set are $1$ and $n−2$ respectively by reading similar problems on other posts here. However, I wasn't able to find a proof that doesn't rely on limits—specifically, I'm looking for a proof that uses only the definition/
ϵ-characterization of infimum and supremum.
I would greatly appreciate any help with this approach!

Replacing the use of limits in the proof here with an $\epsilon$ argument is not at all hard to do.
